# Callback passed in class variables are empty on var_dump

Tags: php, multithreading, callback, pthreads

I have a class that is similar to this striped down version:

```
abstract class MainClass extends Thread{
    protected $events = [];

    public function on($message, callable $callback){
        $this->events[$message] = $callback;
    }
}

class MyClass extends MainClass{
    // has some random methods
}
```

I then run this which creates an instance of the class, it then runs a callback which runs the method in the passed in class.

```
$myClass = new MyClass();
call_user_func_array("myCallback", array($myClass));
var_dump($myClass);

function myCallback($class){
    $class->on("message", function(){
        // Do some stuff
    });
}
```

When I do the var_dump on the class, the `MyClass::$var` array is empty. Why is that?

## Edit

If I don't extend the `Thread` class, this works. Why is the Thread class not allowing me to edit my properties?

Comment: Are You getting any error?

Comment: @taxicala nope, no error

Comment: After running my example it seems to work, but in the real code it doesn't. I have to look into why...

Comment: I am not sure if it matters, but I am using threading, and the callback and the class initialization are running on the same thread according to http://docs.php.net/manual/en/thread.getcurrentthreadid.php

Comment: it seems to have something to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using a `Stackable` object. What I found out, is that arrays are not thread safe, so to accomplish the task I did this:

```
class Events extends Stackable{

    public function add($message, callable $callback){
        $this[$message] = $callback;
    }

}

abstract class MainClass extends Thread{

    protected $events;

    public function __construct(Events $events){
        $this->events = $events;
    }

    public function on($message, callable $callback){
        $this->events->add($message, $callback);
    }

}

class MyClass extends MainClass{
    // has some random methods
}

$evts    = new Events();
$myClass = new MyClass($evts);
call_user_func_array("myCallback", array($myClass));
var_dump($myClass);

function myCallback($class){
    $class->on("My Message", function(){
        // Do some stuff
    });
}
```